# How to resolve the error "jQuery is not defined"?

Tags: jquery, typescript, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I'm working in `asp.net` core And using typescript. I want to use the `select2` option. For that, I use this line:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

When I am running the project, I found the bellowing error:

[image]

How to resolve it?

Comment: You need to add jquery script link above this two line..

Comment: Load jquery before select2.min.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Important Note:-*** jQuery base library need to be added before any third-party-js-library/your-own-written-script-code

So add jQuery base-library like below:-

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery base library needed -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to include jQuery before any third-party js library, e.g.:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to explain where to add jQuery library and why.